# re-authentication(through 6 digit code/2 factor authentication) of user on a particular page/event on Angular app

Tags: authentication, security, oauth, jwt, authorization

User able to login through credentials and able to access website but on particular page/event, one more layer of authentication we want. How we can achieve that ?

I am trying to use AWS Cognito MFA feature. please advice.